# What does determinant of linear operator mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving problem (Linear Algebra by Hoffman, Excercise 5.4.8) :

> Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$. Let $B$ be a fixed element of $V$ and let $T_B$ be the linear operator on $V$ defined by $T_B(A)=AB-BA$. Show that $\det T_B=0$.

But I can not find the meaning of the *determinant of linear operator*, not of matrix, in my textbook.

I assume $\det T=0$ means $T$ is not a bijection, but this does not provide the information about nonzero values of determinant. Moreover, I can not convince my assuming.

Comment: You can easily show, that $\det(STS^{-1}) = \det(T)$ for bijections $S$ (since $\det(AB) = \det A\det B$ and $\det(A^{-1}) = (\det A)^{-1}$), so the determinant is independent of the choice of a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From section 5.6, p. 172, of Hoffman and Kunze:

> ...we see that the determinant of $T$ is the determinant of the matrix
>   which represents $T$ in any ordered basis
>   $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}$.

I haven't been able to find a definition of the determinant of a linear operator that appears prior to problem 5.4.8 in Hoffman and Kunze.  However, the definition is hinted at in problem 5.3.11.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the determinant can be done this way:

1. define a determinant on matrices. Prove that $\det (A B) = \det (B A)$ or, alternatively, that
   $\det (AB) = \det A \times \det B.$
2. define a pseudo-determinant on $E$ (depending on a choice of a certain basis $B$ of $E$), 
   $$\det f = \det M(f,B)
   $$ is the determinant of the matrix of $f$ in the base $B$.
3. prove that this application does not depend on the choixe of the basis, so that the *ad hoc* choice in step 2. does not matter, using the lemma proved in 1.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant is the factor by which volume change. The new volume is the norm of the transformed n-blade, n-[parallelotope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped#Parallelotope), is $\Vert Av_1\wedge\ldots\wedge Av_n\Vert=\vert\det A\vert\cdot \Vert v_1\wedge\ldots\wedge v_n\Vert$. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Transformation_on_alternating_multilinear_n-forms). A zero determinant means that the mapping "collapses" some dimensions, so the map is not an injection.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment of filmor, the basis is irrelevant. Your "$T$ is not a bijection" is the key:
$$T_B(I)= IB − BI = B - B = 0,$$
so $\ker T_B\ne\{0\}$ and $\det T_B = 0.$